При попытке запустить код выдает TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
У меня возникла проблема, пытаюсь запустить код, но выдает ошибку
Не нашел решение гугле, по этому обращаюсь к вам.
Вот сам код
import  pyowm

own = pyowm.owm("00000000000000000000000000000000")
mrg = owm.weather_manager ()

place = input('В каком городе:')

observation = OWM.wather_at_plase(plase)
w = observation.get_wather()

temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')['temp']

print('В городе ' + plase + " сейчас " + w.get_detailed_status())
print("Температура сейчас в районе" + str(temp))

и мне выдает ошибку.

Учу python 2 день, так что не ругайтесь, за возможно столь глупый вопрос

По-моему, не стоит даже бесплатные ключи к апи выкладывать в свободный доступ.

@Qwertiy♦, Спасибо!

Ну у них же пример есть:
from pyowm.owm import OWM
owm = OWM('your-free-api-key')

Значит в твоём варианте:
import pyowm
own = pyowm.owm.OWM("00000000000000000000000000000000")

